# Paypal Webhooks vs direct PaypalApi response

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

Sorry if this question is stupid, but:
Why we should use web-hooks for payments if paypal responds with correct statuses and information about payment, payer, sale etc. when we create payment via REST PaymentAPI. The same with payouts. 
Probably I don't know something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user (purchaser) has the option of using funds from his/her PayPal wallet (PayPal funds), linked credit card(s), or linked bank account(s). Just because the payment has been executed does not mean the funds have been transferred, especially in the case of linked bank account(s). Funds from a checking account, etc. can take several days to transfer.

Comment: So, webhooks, provide additional update functionality for payments. I mean if charging linked bank account will fail webhook will notify me (I hope). BUT... usually webhooks fires after several minutes after user has confirmed his payment, and webhook data does not differs from direct answer. So question mostly is - may I trust direct answer from paypal (and update data from webhook when it fires) or I should use ONLY webhooks?

Comment: You could use both. Compare to pre-REST API, where there is IPN (Instant Payment Notification, think webhook as in your question) and PDT(Payment Data Transfer). While both methods are secure, PDT is more instantaneous than IPN. However, if something was to happen and the merchant's server was inaccessible, IPN would keep trying while PDT would give up. It was sometimes suggested to use both, but test to prevent the merchant's site from processing duplicate payment notifications, i.e. if PDT did go through, do not process IPN.